# php query array => jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I am pretty new to jQuery/AJAX ,so I ran into small trouble.
I want to use PHP query results in my jquery, but can`t manage to do that.
I use this code to call my php function:

```
$(".website_main_configuration_button#1").click(function(){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/admin_functions.php",
    data: {callFunction: "getGlobalConfigSettings"},
    cache: false,
    //dataType: "json", //Do I need this?
    success: function(retuned_value){
        var result = eval(retuned_value);
        for (var index in result){
            alert("..."); // How to access them?
        }
    }
});
```

I use this code to retrieve my PHP array:

```
$resultArray = array();
$result = mysqli_query($dbconnect,"SELECT value FROM config");
for ($i=0;$i<7;$i++){
    $resultArray[]=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);}
echo json_encode($resultArray);
```

And my config table looks like:

```
id | setting | value
```

But I cant figure this method out, because in every post about this problem I just dont understand how to access my array values in jQuery.
Any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: *"//Do I need this?"* yes. but you don't need eval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$(".website_main_configuration_button#1").click(function(){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/admin_functions.php",
    data: {callFunction: "getGlobalConfigSettings"},
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result ){
        result.forEach(function(row) {
            alert(row.value);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the documentation on [jQuery.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).  When JSON data is returned from an AJAX request, it's automatically parsed and returned as an object.  There is no need to `eval` the result.

> If json is specified, the response is parsed using jQuery.parseJSON before being passed, as an object, to the success handler. The parsed JSON object is made available through the responseJSON property of the jqXHR object.